# How to hide filename from url by using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I was wondering how I could hide filename completetely from url using .htaccess.

Currently it is like:
mysite.com/foldername/filename

And I would like it to be like:
mysite.com/foldername

At the moment I use .htacces file for removing only file extensios from url and I would like to upgrade it to only show folder name. We have not leader anything about .htacces yet so I would appreciate pretty direct codes and hints, thank you! :)

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.htm -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.htm

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/tjmediaproductions\.com\/quiz\/" [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Do you need to be able to access multiple different filenames, or only one of them?

Comment: "We have not leader anything about .htacces yet " - we do prefer that you apply some basic research before coming here to ask questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On  # enables url rewriting

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # if requested uri is not directory (!-d)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f # and if there is a file named URI+'.php' (-f)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php # then if there is any thing in uri then rewrite it as uri+'.php'
```

others are the same
    
and about the las part idont know.

```
<br />
<br />
```

and there is another point and question 
    
as you said
    
Currently it is like: mysite.com/foldername/filename
    
And I would like it to be like: mysite.com/foldername
    
 tell me what kind of rule is behind it?
    
do you want to have this

```
    mysite.com/something
```

insted of

```
    mysite.com/something/something.php
```

or use

```
    mysite.com/something
```

insted of

```
    mysite.com/something/anotherthing.php
```

if you want to use first way.
you can use this may be works

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  # if requested uri is directory (-d)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f # and if there is not a file (!-f)
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1/$1.php [NC,L] # foldername/foldername.php
```

or maybe this

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d  # if requested uri is not directory (!-d)
    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1/$1.php [NC,L] # foldername/foldername.php
```

Comment: Basically I just want to hide filename from url, only showing it up to folder name and we have not studied this stuff yet so it does not seems too familar to me. So I mean the first one you wrote about

Comment: I have a Suggestion for you why you dont rename file to index.php.if you do so there is no need to use .htaccess at all.like this. mysite/foldername and it loads mysite/foldername/index.php. what is your purpose?

Comment: I have other filenames under same folder name, cannot name all as index

Comment: there is probably a way with .htaccess but idont know it.but i khow another way that you can do that with php code.called routing how is it?

Comment: Could check how that works. I think it would be fine also :)

Comment: ok did you checked last answer I have sent top. I have edited it?

Comment: I am working on it but I keep receiving internal server errors. Tough I am not sure about did I manage to modify it correctly myself.