# Apache .htaccess Assistance

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm not sure if this is the use of a .htaccess file or not but what I need to do is make it so in the browser, if I visit for example the about page on my website, in the address bar, it shows mydomain.com/about rather than mydomain.com/about.html/.php/.whatever. How would I do this?

Comment: You can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722088/how-to-hide-filename-from-url-by-using-htaccess

Comment: @AlexandreL. From my understanding, that is to hide the filename completely. I just want to hided the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

To hide your file extension, your `.htaccess` should look like this

**Hide PHP extension example**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

To hide multiple file extension, just copy line 2 to 4 and apply different extension.