# Remove path of URL

Tags: php, html, url

I have searched for this problem but couldn't get a good example.
I want to remove/change the path of an url so the user doesn't see the file name without changing the actual file name.

See the below example: 
http://mywebsite.com/OneOfMyRandomPages.php

If I want this to for instance show: 
http://mywebsite.com/

Comment: There is 2 or 3 ways to do that, but how do you expect the user to navigate/browse in your website ? i.e what should looks like an url to another page in your site ?

Comment: You can look into an htaccess file for the url rewrite but will also need to implement some kind of routing to call different scripts based on a path. Look at how http://altorouter.com/ and http://www.slimframework.com/ do this.

Answer (score 0):

edit htaccess (or if doesn't exist, create)  and put this code:

```
DirectoryIndex OneOfMyRandomPages.php
```

and if you think maybe one day this page will remove, use this code to automatic next file will be default

```
DirectoryIndex OneOfMyRandomPages.php twoOfMyRandomPages.php ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your best bet is looking for a .htaccess solution.  I highly suggest simply googling "remove file endings htaccess" but the general principle is that you should add a RewriteRule to your .htaccess file which redirects all requests for "/test.php" to "/test" and then every time you get a request for "/test" show "/test.php"  more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722088/how-to-hide-filename-from-url-by-using-htaccess)