# Is there a possible solution on how to hide file name in PHP or .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change my url path to this:

**`localhost/sampleproject/validation.php`**

to

**`localhost/sampleproject/`**

I want to secure my file path. is there a code in .htaccess? if there is I will create .htaccess but i have no clue where to start, still learning to php thank you

Comment: Your question looks similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722088/how-to-hide-filename-from-url-by-using-htaccess

Please check and see if this answer works for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide filename from url by using .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15722088/how-to-hide-filename-from-url-by-using-htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

that type of change usually hides index.php if you need to run code in a validation.php i might suggest including it within your index.php you can do so conditionally if necessary using include() or require_once()  if you do that the user will have no knowledge of that file on the fronted. here's some examples of that https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_includes.asp

reference the links in comments of your question but as I said generally with apache you can configure it to not show the index.php but other than that it's per folder basis.

you may also want to look into creating some routes to trick the browser abit if that's your approach.

here's an example http://blogs.shephertz.com/2014/05/21/how-to-implement-url-routing-in-php/

or you can always use a framework such as symfony or Laravel which have route implementations for you to use.

Happy Coding.